# How to programmatically render an Openlayers map in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, openlayers

My searching has turned up virtually nothing. All of the documentation I can find is for the Drupal 6 version. I need to figure out how to render an Openlayers map programmatically (using the `openlayers_render_map` function, I assume). Ultimately I want to create with the form API a map to select between multiple locations that match a search, so that I can get the canonical address and a WKT string describing the exact location.

This is a rather open-ended question, and what I really want is a link to some well-written documentation. However, as I'm coming to the conclusion that no such thing exists, a more specific question would be: **how do I design an Openlayers map in PHP code and render it in an arbitrary template?** It will *not* display data stored in nodes, or even anywhere persistent at all, so using Views is *not* an option. Additionally, **how can I begin to write Javascript that interacts with the map in order to select certain locations or retrieve the currently selected location?**

Comment: Hi, I have the same question you have, I posted your question in the Drupal forum looking for some help. http://drupal.org/node/1955036

Answer (score 1):

To render a map:

```
$map = openlayers_map_load('my_map');
$output = openlayers_render_map($map->data,$map->name);
```

To Interact with map in js:

```
var ol_map = $('.openlayers-container .openlayers-map').data('openlayers');
```

Comment: Not helpful. What do I get from `openlayers_map_load`? What is in `$map->data`? What is allowed for `$map->name` and what does that argument control? What is in `.data('openlayers')`? It looks like I can use that to read from the map. How would I change the map with javascript?

Comment: if you print $output you will see your map.

Comment: How to see the map you rendered was not one of the questions in my comment. I need to know how to change the rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that using views isn't an option? Bear with me as I suggest a crazy idea:

Make a map view, where the map itself accepts lat/lng as arguments (or some other geo value of your choosing) then make a map data view that doesn't really contain anything meaningful at all. Link 'em up. Then send your map page arguments from your geocoder directly.

I am working on something similar with limited success, but it just feels like something that should be possible...

Comment: Even if that solved the first part of my problem, it doesn't even begin to solve the problem of making the map actually interactive.

Answer (score 0):

```
$map = openlayers_map_load('your_map');
$map->data['layer_activated']['your_layer'] = 'your_layer';
$map->data['layers']['your_layer'] = 'your_layer';
$map->data['behaviors']['openlayers_behavior_zoomtolayer']['zoomtolayer']['your_layer'] = 'your_layer';    
$output = openlayers_render_map($map->data,$map->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenLayers 3 the way to embed a map in a (say) module-generated page, this is what I [found in the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/openlayers/openlayers-3x-api) and successfully used in my own project:

```
//$map_name = your map name
$map = \Drupal\openlayers\Openlayers::load('map', $map_name);
$rendered = $map->render();
```

To generate a map "on the fly," the [OL3 API](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/openlayers/-/blob/7.x-3.x/openlayers.api.php?ref_type=heads) seems to have hooks that allow this.